# How do I set my hasura permission to only see the rows of my table corresponding to a user?

Tags: postgresql, hasura

Here's the thing. I have the 3 tables depicted here:

[image]

People on my application can place orders. Then, I want

- a user with `rex` permission to see **all** the `orders` table's rows
- a user with `delivery` permission to only see the rows of the `orders` table that have the `zip` column set to the `delivery` user's `zip`

From the `orders` table, I can get for each order a `zip`. With the table `zip_user`, I can get a `user_id` out of a `zip`. Out of that `user_id`, I can get the delivery user from the `users` table.

While it is trivial to get the `rex` to see all of the `orders` table, I have not yet been able to configure the permissions for the `delivery` user. What do I need to do?

In other words, given the user performing a select on the `orders` table has `x-hasura-user-id` set to some user id and `x-hasura-role` set to `delivery`, how does that user get only the rows from the `orders` table that match with the `zip`s associated with that user's `user_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasura has the concept of relations. If you have foreign keys, it makes the relations automatically, if not you can make them yourself in the UI. Once the relationships have been set up, you will be able to set deep permissions, so on the `orders` table, you'll be able to use `users.id`.

Start here: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/relationships/index.html